# Application language setup for scheme

Tags: xcode10, ios12

It seems that Xcode10 scheme's application language (Edit scheme > Run > Options) has no effect to my `Locale.current` on simulator/device. I'm having setup like this:

[image]

It's giving me `cs_US` as a current `Locale`:

[image]

Has anyone a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. I have a czech language set as a development language and no english localization yet. Czech (cs) is a fallback language for english then.